# How to convince my team leader not to lose faith in me?

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication, team, unprofessional-behavior

I am in a company for 3 months now in these 3 months I have missed my deadlines and gave faulty codes and each time I asked apology and assured him of better performance but I couldn't do due to external factors like 1)dependency on other teams
2)new organisation work culture 
and internal my inherent factors
1)lack of confidence
2)lack of focus and stress due to this new organisation culture/

I have trouble getting work done from other teams

I have made my own mistakes on my code as well.

Now I am out of excuses and he has lost confidence in me !

I have to convince him by talking ?

what can i say to convince him ?

About me:
I am the best worker in my previous company

what do I mean work culture in this new company ?
Here I have to wait for other teams to finish their part and their part is buggy always and my part always has to depend on others
Here guys are very tricky ...they knowingly confuse others
The team in spread across geographically on different timezones
They always blame others and they're masters in that 
They speak about something without know anything substantial on that 
The teams communication medium is Skype forum and JIRA tool.

I am really helpless somebody give me suggestion on how to convince my boss ?

How to adapt myself into this new culture ?

Any help is appreciated !

**Update:**

we're working in agile methodology and means of communication is skype forum,jira...In a skype forum there would be 50 people each will communicate using this forum so everyone will get notification this itself is distracting ..so for each notification i have to see if they're asking me ? its really stalling my ongoing works and in the forum they easily project themselves as they know everything and infact as they project like this it leads to confusion and wasting the time...I can't do anything about it because most of the guys are senior like having 4 to 14 years more experience than me...and it will make them enemies and I won't get cooperation...you know they may play office politics as well.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't take ownership of any of your missed deadlines, bad code and other stuff? Is it that everyone else is out to get you? That is how this sounds where I doubt you are perfect.

Comment: Not everyone is a good fit at every company. Maybe this company isn't a fit for you. The best and only way to get your boss to have faith in you is for you to do a good job consistently. Nothing else will do it. Take charge of your responsibilities and don't blame others. Make sure the work you do "works". You can't blame others for "your work" that doesn't get done. Figure out how to do your work despite what others do. Demonstrate that you are in control of your assignments. Task lists are great. I don't always keep a task list but once I start feeling overwhelmed, that's my #1 goto option.

Comment: The first thing to remember is that all of your team mates work in the same environment. If they're doing better, that's good and bad. It's good, because you have someone to ask about how to get better. It's bad, because all of your peers are in a similar shoddy situation, and you're _still_ worse than them.

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696

Comment: @JBKing I am also neither perfect the reason is the ruckus the other team guys are doing and I am not used to work in such a environment .it causes panic,stress and adrenaline rush.

Comment: @Dunk - Yes ,this company isn't fit for me..but I would like to take it as challenge and adapt myself here

Comment: @NagaR - a company culture or environment shouldn't be a challenge. You can either spend time and energy getting better at your job(programming by the sound of it) or spend that time and energy 'adapting' to what sounds like a terrible place to work. Something there had better be amazing - the leave, the pay, the benefits - because frankly it sounds like a poorly architected org. Also, frankly, you need to come to terms with the idea that there may come a time where your choices are leave for somewhere a better fit or get fired. There's no shame in looking for something that's better for you.

Comment: @Nahkki yes you're right the monthly salary,leave plans those things are really great when compared to other companies here that's one of the reason why I want to stick around in this company and another reason we'll have lots of free time so I can learn a lot ..The thing the work will come suddenly and we'd be busy that time and that time We've to depend on other and things I have mentioned..

Answer (score 8):

Your first step is to breathe. Your current panic comes through your question and I can only image how frantic you come across in your conversations with your actual boss, which won't serve you well.

You have a couple of issues and your first step should be to identify them. Once they have been identified you should start separating them into things you can effect and things you cannot effect. Let's clarify the issues you have described and go through recommendations for each:

"*I have made my own mistakes on my code as well*." The long and short response to this is to stop making mistakes. But, since we are none of us perfect, 
a better answer is to examine the types of mistakes you are making. How are you writing code? Are you writing tests for your code? How can you validate that your code does what you claim it does? Is there a review process? Consider, instead of offering excuses, providing some recommendations to your boss on ways to ensure your(and your team's) code is good - code reviews, work flows, unittests. These are all powerful tools to mitigate the inevitable mistakes that occur. Additionally you should take time to identify the mistakes you are making. Take some time to figure out where those mistakes are coming from and what you can do to minimize them - are you rushing? Are you being lazy? Are you lacking in some background knowledge?

"I have trouble getting work done from other teams" This can be subdivided even further.

*Other teams are missing their deadlines which effects mine*
How are deadlines being set? If they are using email, forums and Jiira there should be a record of promised timelines and deliverables. In theory there would be a project manager on top of this but, for the moment at least, you need to be that person. When they miss their deadline you need to tell your boss *immediately* that your timeline will be effected. What is happening right now is that they are causing delays and you are eating the shit for it. Keep records, force them to set a timeline in writing somewhere. Don't wait until you've missed your deadline to tell your supervisor(s). Keep your team(from the bottom to the top) in the loop about when you are able to start coding on something and when the projected delivery date is. Are you having regular stand-ups with someone from the team you are receiving code from? If not instigate them immediately, you need to take ownership of communication between the teams you are working with.

*Other teams are submitting nonfunctioning or buggy code*
What is the process for testing their code? What is the process for measuring the specs against the deliverable? This sounds less like they are delivering buggy code and more like you are eating shit for them delivering non-spec code. Are you immediately telling your manager whenever code is delivered? Do you immediately raise any bugs to both your manager and the other team? You **cannot** sit on problems and expect good results. So far a lot of your intra-team issues are related to lack of communication and process - start building those things and you'll see a quick turnaround with the problems.

*"I have to convince him by talking ?"* There is almost nothing you could say at this point to convince your boss that you are not the problem. In an ideal world there would be someone on top of the intra-team communication and project management. Since that does not appear to be the case you need to step up and handle that. It is fair, at this point, to note that you have worked in the company for only 3 months. You should have a mentor or direct-report manager who you can go to with these problems. There should have been an on-boarding process.  The lack of these things means that this is a pretty brutal environment to get up and running within. That being said - you can't *say* anything to convince your boss, but what you can do is come to him with some action items. Recommend processes by which you intent to minimize your mistakes, request guidance on how to report changing deadlines before they become a problem, chat about how to best report bugs in code from upstream.

In order to succeed at your new company you need to take a deep breath, stop failing about and begin to implement and support procedures that will stop the problems from flowing from upstream and landing in your lap. It may be, ultimately, that this company is a poor fit for you, there's no shame in that. But in this, or any other job, you need to be willing and capable of taking control. It sounds like things can't get much worse where you are right now so this may be an excellent opportunity to attempt this.

Comment: As we're using agile methodology everybody has to work simultaneously.I am a mobile app developer I have to depend API team to complete their work so that I can test my code and implement what happens here is they say they've completed a API and when I try it works that time and it breaks after that ...and if I highlight the problem they do a temp fix and it breaks again.So when I try the other API the previous one works and this breaks like that

Comment: I can't blame API team for all misery ..Because they in turn have to depend on Systems team,VPN team,Cloud team etc...so If a problem happens they take more time to find where the bug is ..But at the end of they it all becomes burden for me and I have to finish it in the short time that's where the panic/anxiety attacks comes in and I also leave a bug unintentionally given the short period of time.

Comment: @NagaR Are you really sure you _need_ the data provided by the API? Can you not use dummy objects/values until the API works again? Your code should be able to be finished without the API, if you know the structure of the data to be returned.

Comment: @Jonast92 - part of our work includes that we have to make sure that API works correct...Not to call out anything on the product delivery time...and by the way the format of json response structure is volatile its bound to change often...But we never know when it changed if we missed some forum conversations...I don't mean to be blaming on others But these are fact.

Comment: If the JSON response format changes at the last moment then you should *immediately* raise the issue to your supervisor/boss. It's fair to blame the other team(though from your description you should be blaming management for having no specs for deliverables) but with it comes the responsibility on your end to raise and own issues in your own house. If the JSON responses are often changed you should look for ways to handle JSON that does not require much changing on your end. Consider generic response and request models that are used in your code. Thus sheltering your code from their changes.

Comment: @NagaR I believe that you could still mock up data, then work with the API team to make sure that the data meets the format you specified. That way you get your work done concurrent with them, and can catch problems a lot quicker.

Answer (score 4):

Track down the people causing you trouble and send them a mail with examples why there missed deadlines or buggy code caused you trouble and that they should get their stuff straight instead of blaming others. You want to get your work done properly and on time and for this you need the right base material on time.

This will either get you lots of respect or will end in you being fired, in both cases you are better off. All assuming you don't depend on exactly this job and can find a new one.

Stop apologizing, it makes you look weak. Tell your boss that you have trouble with the people delivering to you and you are looking into improving the situation. You hope to get it done, otherwise you will need to talk about another system to determine deadlines, for example counting from the time when they deliver the real thing. Show confidence, even if you don't have it, and then go kick some butts.

If you get the suppliers working properly and then still cause bugs, start working on these. But prematurely taking all the blame and stressing yourself out to improve will just kill you. If you were a good worker so far, you should be here too under the right conditions.